# Correct synonym for "original" in this context

Tags: adjectives

I have the following text:

"I will be selling multiple copies of the different posters, fan art, ... that I made."
"I will also be selling original drawings".

It seems to me that in the second sentence, the word "original" seems to mean "The artwork from the first sentence is not original"

I am looking for the perfect way to describe that I'll be selling both copies of digital artwork, but also single drawings that were made with traditional means such as markers, pencils, ... of which there exist no copies at all.

Comment: Are the copies sold as physical prints or digital files?

Comment: I can't agree with the OP's take on the use of the word "original" to mean that the artwork from the first sentence is not original. My reading of the text informs me that the artist has made copies of his artwork (posters, etc.) which he intends to sell PLUS one off, original drawings by the same artist. I see no reason to change any of the text to convey any other meaning that the OP seems to want to convey.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not clear what you're asking. I will rescind that vote if you edit your question to answer the following questions: (1) Does "that I made" modify "copies" or "different posters, fan art, ..."? (2) When you say "original drawings", do you mean *your*  original drawings? (3) Do the original drawings have anything to do with the original posters, fan art, ...?

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I think your text as it stands makes clear the distinction between 'originals' and 'copies'.  It might be clearer still if you reversed the order -

*I will also be selling original drawings and also reproductions of the different posters, fan art, ... that I made.*

I'm not sure, these days, whether it's reasonable to imagine that *anything* cannot be copied...

***Original*** - *Designating the thing, as a document, text, picture, etc., from which another is copied or reproduced* (OED)